# How can I disable automatic updates in ionic-cli 3.30?

Tags: ionic3, ionic-cli

I need to stop Ionic CLI from checking for updates whenever I run an ionic command. This prevents me from even running the app offline. An illustration is as :

`C:\Users\TO-004\Desktop\EzyMarketplace\EzyExtension-App-2017-master>ionic serve
? The Ionic CLI has an update available (3.3.0 => 3.4.0)! Would you like to install it? (Y/n)`

Answer (score 4):

Ionic seems to compare the release date by the timestamp of "lastCommand" in `~/.ionic/config.json`. If that date is later than the release date it will not ask you the question.

Just change the timestamp to a future date, not an ideal solution but it seems to work.

Comment: With 3.5.0 this doesn't work. The cli updates `lastCommand` each time it runs.

Answer (score 4):

In 3.5.0 you can turn off the CLI's interactive mode by either using the `--no-interactive` flag or by manually setting `cliFlags.interactive` to `false` in `~/.ionic/config.json`.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how can you hide only one site (MSE) from your profile but not others?

Comment: @iBug There's a "Hide Communities" option (under "Site Settings") when editing your profile.

Answer (score 3):

My problem resolved with:

```
ionic --no-interactive -v
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change definitely by setting  daemon.updates to false in `~/.ionic/config.json`

Answer (score 0):

You can change definitely by setting  `daemon.updates` to false in `~/.ionic/config.json`.

ex.

```
{
   ....
   "daemon" :{
      "updates": false
    }    
    ...
}
```